# C# parse filter string

Tags: c#

I need to parse following string,

```
var filter = "username eq \"john.smith\""
```

and  get,

```
var leftPart = "username"
var operator = "eq"
var rightPart = "john.smith"
```

What is the best way to do this?

I need to parse complex queries like,

```
filter=userType eq "Employee" and emails.type eq "work"
```

Yeah, I looked into string split, regex, iterate by char. Is there a library to do these things? I am looking for a complex filter query parsing. I looked into Antlr, but unfortunately I cannot get it working .net core + VS2017.

Comment: split by space and remove special chars that's it. :)

Comment: Are the ``\`` characters part of string, or something you included so we'd see the quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to parse complex queries

Woo boy, have you opened a can of worms.

If you're lucky, all you really need are tokens to pass somewhere else for the actual filter, in which case searching Google or NuGet for a C# lexer or tokenizer should give you fairly simple solutions that are ready to go.

If you actually need to implement the filter from these tokens yourself, you need to look deeper. Ideally, you're using a well-known grammar of some kind (ie: a filter for elastic search or parse.com), and there will be an existing parser you can use. But if not, there are still some tools out there that can help you. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/index.html) is one of these, and it has a [C# library](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/csharp-target.md) you can use. .Net also has some built-in support for [Domain Specific Languages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943825.aspx).

But the main thing is to avoid writing this code from scratch yourself. If you're really dealing with complex queries, taking the time to learn this stuff now will save you a ton of grief in the long run.

Comment: tnx for the advice, I am looking forward to implement  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7644#section-3.4.2.2 SCIM spec. I will look into these tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] substrings = filter.Split(' ');
leftPart = substrings[0] ...
```

and remove " in rightpart (as Mohit mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it manually like this:

```
var filter = "username eq \"john.smith\"";
var parts = filter.Split(" \"\\".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var leftPart = parts[0];
var oper = parts[1];
var rightPart = parts[2];
```